# How to store each element to dictionary and count dictionary value with pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I want to count elements value of dictionary. I try with this code:

```
def f_items(data, steps=0):

     items = defaultdict(int)    
     for element in data:
         if element in data:
             items[element] += 1
         else:
             items[element] = 1
     return items.items()

data = [[1, 2, 3, 'E'], [1, 2, 3, 'E'], [5, 2, 7, 112, 'A'] ] 
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
items = rdd.flatMap(lambda data: [y for y in f_items(data)], True)
print (items.collect())
```

The output of this code is shown below:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), ('E', 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), ('E', 1), (5, 1), (2, 1), (7, 1), (112, 1), ('A', 1)]
```

But, it should show the result following:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), ('E', 2), (5, 1), (7, 1), (112, 1), ('A', 1)]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your last step should be a reduceByKey function call on the items rdd.

```
final_items = items.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y)
print (final_items.collect())
```

You can look into [this link](http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-reducebykey-example/) to see some examples of reduceByKey in scala, java and python.